# Set array method on java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class `arrayFun` with the variable

```
  int[] _array;
```

I have a method setArray:

```
        public void setArray(int [] array) 
        {
         _array = array;
        }
```

1. Is my set method implementation correct ?

2).How can I use this method in other class with main ?

I've tried some ridiculous options like:

```
       arrayFun A = new arrayFun(some_constructor_values);
       A.setArray(1,2,3,4,5);
```

That option of course doesn't work...

Comment: If you're still learning maybe it would be good to follow [official code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: ` A.setArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});`

Comment: They're a good idea learning or not. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
A.setArray(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this declare the argument as a "varargs" argument as follows:

```
public void setArray(int ... array) {
     _array = array;
}
```

and then this will work:

```
A.setArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

You can do the same with a constructor argument.

---

While I have your attention, it is important that you learn the Java naming conventions, and learn to follow them strictly.

- A class name should **always** start with an uppercase letter
- A variable name should **always** start with a lowercase letter ... unless it is a `static final` constant.
- Using an underscore as a prefix generally frowned on.

For more information, read the [Java Style Guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

So your example class should look like this:

```
public class ArrayFun {

    private int[] array;

    public void setArray(int ... array) {
       this.array = array;
    }
}
```

and should be used like this:

```
ArrayFun a = new ArrayFun();
a.setArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Nice. It's the first time I've heard of Java varargs. I'm familiar with the use from perl and javascript, but it seems a bit "dirty" for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead

```
public void setArray(int... array) { _array = array; }

// later
ArrayFun a = new ArrayFun(some_constructor_values);
a.setArray(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Unless you take a copy of the array, you will be using the same array in the caller and callee.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do doesn't really make sense. Also, why use a function to "set the array", why not just set the array directly:

`_array = newArray`

You can also set an array's values like this:

`int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Answer (score 0):

Your method's signature is :

```
public void setArray(int[] array)
```

So it accepts only one argument that is of type array of integers.

But in your method call, you are calling it as:

```
A.setArray(1,2,3,4,5);
```

In this you are passing 5 arguments to the method. So it does not match any method with 5 arguments. Thats why it does not work.

You should pass one array of integers.

You can do it in various ways :

```
int myArr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
A.setArray(myArr);
```

or

```
A.setArray(new int[]new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting array the way you did is fine. But what you are setting from **A.setArray(1,2,3,4,5);** will throw you error saying "**Method setArray(int,int,int,int,int) is not found**".

You can do something like `int[] ar = { 1, 2 };
        a.setArray(ar);`